# Return more than one id in django

Tags: python, django

So I brought the django-polls tutorial into a simple blog. Some posts have polls linked to them through a Foreign Key. The problem I'm having is when I "Vote" or click "Vote again" It re-loads the post but it re-loads using the id for the poll.

Example:

```
post1 - linked to - poll1
post2 - no poll
post3 - linked to - poll2
```

so when I vote or click vote again on the poll in post3 it loads post2.

I need to get the id of the post and the poll.

Here is my code:
models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def display_mySafeField(self):
        return mark_safe(self.body)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total_votes = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    voted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question


# Choice for the poll
class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    percentage = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice
```

views.py:

```
def vote(request, poll_id):
    global choice
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the poll voting form.
        return render_to_response('post.html', {
            'poll': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
            }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        p.total_votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        p.voted = True
        p.save()

        choices = list(p.choice_set.all())
        for choice in choices:
            percent = choice.votes*100/p.total_votes
            choice.percentage = percent
            choice.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("blog.views.post", args=[poll_id]))

def vote_again(request, post_pk):
    try:
        p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=post_pk)
    except (KeyError, Poll.DoesNotExist):
    # Redisplay the poll voting form.
        return render_to_response('post.html', {
        'poll': p,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        p.voted = False
        p.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("blog.views.post", args=[post_pk]))
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^revote/(\d+)/$', 'blog.views.vote_again'),
url(r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'blog.views.vote'),
```

It all works on the first post and poll, but it crashes when I want to add polls to posts that dont have the same pk.

Any help or direction will be appreciated. I've been messing around for about 2 hours and this is the first time django has frustrated me. Apologies in advance because I'm 99% sure this is a stupid question.

Comment: It's better if you add models code too.

Comment: Just added them. Also, I'm not using users yet, It's just me who can vote and re-vote.

Comment: In `def vote_again(request, post_pk)` semantically you're passing post_pk but querying Poll model. Is that intended?

Comment: I tried p = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=poll_id) but then vote again doesnt do anything, the way it is works on the first poll just not posts/polls that dont have the same pk.. I need the pk of the poll but I need to reload the post using the pk of the post. Part of me wants to make every poll pk equal the post's pk. But wouldn't that be the same thing as adding the poll model to the post model?

Comment: when I click re-vote I get a url that ends with /revote/3/

Comment: don't post your local urls. They won't work.

Comment: I need it to end with /revote/2/    2 being the pk for the poll so it resets the "voted" for that poll, but I need to reload the post that corresponds to the post's pk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pk` means primary key. So there you're trying to get a poll object whose id is same to the post_pk.

Try,

```
p = get_object_or_404(Poll, post_id=post_pk)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna go slam my head into a wall right now. :) Thanks again.